# How to disable all checkboxes when page loads in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm working on this table that has checkboxes for each row. Basically, I want all of the email input fields to be disabled once page loads. If the users clicks on the checkbox that belongs to a row then the email input field for that row should be enabled so the user can type in an email. Finally, if the user clicks on the **Select all** checkbox all of the input fields should be enabled/disabled. For some reason I can only disabled the first, second and last input field once page loads. My **Select All** checkbox is not working properly either :(. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please? Thanks in advance!

```
          var users = $("tr")
                    .filter(function () {
                        return $(this).find('.inputEmail').val() !== "" && $(this).find(".input_checkbox").is(':checked');
                    })
                    .map(function () {
                        var $row = $(this);
                        return {
                            firstName: $row.find('.fullName').text(),
                            number: $row.find('.usersPhoneNumber').text(),
                            email: $row.find('.inputEmail').val()
                        }
                    })
                    .get();
            console.log('Array containing all users with an email:');
            console.log(users);
```

**Here's my code - LIVE DEMO:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkAll").change(function() {
    $(".input_checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).each(function() {
      enable_disable_input(this);
      var nameValue = $(this).attr("name");
      var inputFieldNameValue = $.trim(nameValue);
      var inputFieldString = "customer-name-inputField";
      var inputFieldId = inputFieldNameValue + inputFieldString;
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        enable_disable_input(this);
        $("#" + inputFieldId).prop('placeholder', "Enter email address");
      } else {
        $("#" + inputFieldId).prop('placeholder', "");
        enable_disable_input(this);
      }
    });
  });

  function enable_disable_input(checkbox) {
    var input_id = checkbox.id.replace('-checkbox', '-inputField');
    $("#" + input_id).prop('disabled', !checkbox.checked);
  }
  $(".input_checkbox").change(function() {
    var nameValue = $(this).attr("name");
    var inputFieldNameValue = $.trim(nameValue);
    var inputFieldString = "customer-name-inputField";
    var inputFieldId = inputFieldNameValue + inputFieldString;
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      enable_disable_input(this);
      $("#" + inputFieldId).prop('placeholder', "Enter email address");
    } else {
      $("#" + inputFieldId).prop('placeholder', "");
      enable_disable_input(this);
    }
  });
  $(".input_checkbox").each(function() {
    enable_disable_input(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:1140px;">
  <br/>
  <table>
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom">Select All
          <br/>
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" value="" />
        </td>
        <td width="5"></td>
        <td width="200" valign="bottom">Name</td>
        <td align="center" class="table-col-phone" style="padding-left:20px;">Phone # / Extension</td>
        <td width="50"></td>
        <td valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 90px;">Email</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Group1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">
          <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="0customer-name-checkbox" name="0 " value="">
        </td>
        <td class="fullName">Ben Morris</td>
        <td align="left" class="usersPhoneNumber">3033422109</td>
        <td width="50"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" class="inputEmail" name="0" id="0customer-name-inputField" placeholder="" value="" />
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="center">
          <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="1customer-name-checkbox" name="1 " value="">
        </td>
        <td class="fullName">Mike Jeff</td>
        <td align="left" class="usersPhoneNumber">3037777777</td>
        <td width="50"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" class="inputEmail" name="1" id="1customer-name-inputField" placeholder="" value="" />
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Group2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">
          <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="0customer-name-checkbox" name="0 " value="">
        </td>
        <td class="fullName">Ana McLwius</td>
        <td align="left" class="usersPhoneNumber">3039899231</td>
        <td width="50"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" class="inputEmail" name="0" id="0customer-name-inputField" placeholder="" value="" />
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="center">
          <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="1customer-name-checkbox" name="1 " value="">
        </td>
        <td class="fullName">Zumia Brown</td>
        <td align="left" class="usersPhoneNumber">3033213453</td>
        <td width="50"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" class="inputEmail" name="1" id="1customer-name-inputField" placeholder="" value="" />
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Group3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="center">
          <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="0customer-name-checkbox" name="0 " value="">
        </td>
        <td class="fullName">Bryan Smith</td>
        <td align="left" class="usersPhoneNumber">3033222098</td>
        <td width="50"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" class="inputEmail" name="0" id="0customer-name-inputField" placeholder="" value="" />
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="center">
          <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="1customer-name-checkbox" name="1 " value="">
        </td>
        <td class="fullName">Junior White</td>
        <td align="left" class="usersPhoneNumber">3030098342</td>
        <td width="50"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" class="inputEmail" name="1" id="1customer-name-inputField" placeholder="" value="" />
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"></td>
        <td align="center">
          <input class="input_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="2customer-name-checkbox" name="2 " value="">
        </td>
        <td class="fullName">Peter McDonald</td>
        <td align="left" class="usersPhoneNumber">3037777777</td>
        <td width="50"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="email" class="inputEmail" name="2" id="2customer-name-inputField" placeholder="" value="" />
          <br/>
          <br/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </table>
  <button id="submitButton" type="button" class="sign-in-button" style="text-align: center;margin-left: 428px;" value="Submit" />Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Try ` $(checkbox).prop('disabled', !checkbox.checked);` instead of disabling with `id` of the element in your `enable_disable_input` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search email input based on the current element. You are having duplicate ids.

try this:

`$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type;"text"]').attr("disabled", !this.checkbox);`

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/kfvkr4gw/7/)

Note I have taken leisure to update your code. Hope it helps!

#### Getting Data

You can try something like this:

Note I have updated `Group label` rows and have added class in it.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/kfvkr4gw/8/)

```js
$("#submitButton").on("click", function() {
  var result = {};
  var group_id = "";
  $("table tr").each(function(index, row) {
    var $row = $(row)
    group_id = $row.hasClass("section-label") ? $row.find("td:first").text() : group_id;
    if (group_id && $row.find(".input_checkbox").is(':checked') && $row.find('.inputEmail').val().trim() !== "") {
      result[group_id] = result[group_id] || [];
      result[group_id].push({
        firstName: $row.find('.fullName').text(),
        number: $row.find('.usersPhoneNumber').text(),
        email: $row.find('.inputEmail').val()
      });
    }
  });
  console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro!

Comment: @HenryDev I have updated the fiddle with few minor changes. You should ideally use `$(document).ready()` as an `Init` function, and not code everything in it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: is there anyway to create an array that contains each group after clicking on Submit? I need that array so I can use ajax and send it to my server

Comment: You just want emails or all data?

Comment: I want all the data for each row

Comment: I just added some code to my question so you can take a look at it please( the code is in the very beginning ) . That code works just fine if my table had single rows. It does return an array of each row

Comment: In simple words what I want is a multidimensional array that contains 3 arrays (the 3 Groups), and each sub array will contain each row for each user. Does that make sense?

Comment: My multidimensional array will look like this:  [[Group1], [Group2], [Group3]], and each Group will have each row that belongs to that group.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Obviously because of the duplicated ids.

try this:

```
function enable_disable_input(checkbox) {
 $(checkbox).parents('tr').find('input[type="email"]').prop('disabled', !checkbox.checked);
}
```

Comment: It didn't fix the issue. Can you share any live code like jsfiddle or codepen? Thanks

Comment: Sure thing [https://jsfiddle.net/v3Lk76vu/](https://jsfiddle.net/v3Lk76vu/)

Comment: your answer doesn't work!. If I click on each checkbox then  the email input field that belongs to that row should be enabled. Your answer doesn't do that

Comment: Of course it did :D, I'm using chrome just open the jsfiddle and try it yourself !

Comment: Voila :D [http://recordit.co/6ouvVMeYL0](http://recordit.co/6ouvVMeYL0)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems a little messy, something like this would work and it's more readable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#checkAll").change(function () {
                $(".input_checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).each(function () {
                  var input = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='email']");
                  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                      $(input).prop('disabled', false);
                      $(input).prop('placeholder', "Enter email address");
                  }
                  else {
                      $(input).prop('placeholder', "");
                      $(input).prop('disabled', true);
                  }
                  });
            });
            $(".input_checkbox").change(function () {
                var input = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='email']");

                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $(input).prop('disabled', false);
                    $(input).prop('placeholder', "Enter email address");
                }
                else {
                    $(input).prop('placeholder', "");
                    $(input).prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
            $('.inputEmail').each(function(){
               $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            })
        });
```

[full working example](https://jsfiddle.net/kfvkr4gw/3/)

Also, you should remove the duplicated ID's.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!